# Is there a way to display `free` updates in place without outputing new lines?

Tags: memory, unix

When I do `free -m -s 1`

it gives something like this:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3789        3022         347          90         419         377
Swap:          1023        1016           7

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3789        3022         347          90         419         377
Swap:          1023        1016           7

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3789        3022         347          90         419         377
Swap:          1023        1016           7

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3789        3022         347          90         419         377
Swap:          1023        1016           7
```

Is there a way to just display one set of info:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3789        3022         347          90         419         377
Swap:          1023        1016           7
```

and ask `free` to refresh those info every 1 second for me?

Comment: Terminals generally print new output at the bottom, with the old stuff scrolling "up"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
watch -n 1 free -m
```

You can use `watch` with other commands (e.g. `watch df -h`). It does one thing and does it well.

Note if you want to watch complex commands, you need to quote them right:

```
watch 'df | grep tmpfs'
watch 'free; df'
```

Comment: For people's information, If you are using Mac instead of Linux, you might not have the `watch` command installed, and you can install it using `brew install watch`